Default whitespaces in HTML/CSS code in VSC
in this HTML element:
<p style="text-align: left;"></p>

Visual Studio Code inserts a default blank between : and l. How can I change the default settings, so it doesn't insert this blank after the colon, but inserts a default blank after the semicolon in HTML/CSS?
I tried to find settings in VSC that allow the control of default white spaces, but couldn't.
Pauly

It's normal to have a space after the colon but not after the semicolon so I would leave the formatting as is. If you want to change your formatter you can goto settings > default formatter in vscode
